# How to use the regex in rest assured

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, rest-assured

Like i have to validate in name it should accept only the alphabets value if any numeric value or special char is entered than in response it should give an error.

Note i want to use regex on every key.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consult this article [ask]. One thing this site looks for is some research before a user asks a question. What research have you done and where did you get stuck? It's likely this type of question will be closed, so please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through the response and get the element and store it in a variable of String type.
Then you can use contains method to check if any special character or numeric value which you want to check is present or not.eg of contain method

```java
text.contains("[0-9]+")
```